# Prove: $a \sin x + b \cos x = c \sin(x + d)$

Tags: trigonometry

Can anyone help me with that?

Prove that: For $a, b\in \mathbb{R}$ there is $c, d \in \mathbb{R}$, so that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ applies:

$$a \sin x + b \cos x = c \sin(x + d).$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

$$a\sin x+b\cos x=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\Biggl(\frac a{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin x+\frac b{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos x\Biggr) $$

Now $a'=\frac a{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ and $b'=\frac b{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\;$ satisfy the equality $a'^2+b'^2=1$, so there is a unique $c$ such that $\: 0\le c<2\pi$ and
\begin{cases}
\cos c=\dfrac a{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},\\
\sin c=\dfrac b{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.
\end{cases}

Answer (score 0):

If $b=0$ the equality is trivial.

If $b\neq 0$ we have
$$a \sin x +b \cos x= \sqrt{a^2+b^2}(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \sin x+ \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \cos x).$$
Now remark that there exists $d\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\cos d$ and $\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\sin d$. Then using sinus of sum formula you get
$$a \sin x +b \cos x = c \sin(x+d),$$
with $c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.